# AsyncFileUpload OnUploadedComplete not firing within DIV

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asyncfileupload

I have what I think is a pretty basic setup for using the ajaxcontroltoolkit's AsyncFileUpload control.  Basically the control works correctly if I take it out of the div, but when I put it inside the div it doesn't fire the OnUploadedComplete server-side event anymore.

How this works is you rollover the image you want to change, click 'update image' and it opens a dialog (which is the div the AsyncFileUpload control is in) and allows you to upload a new image.

```
<div id="dialog-message" style="display: none;" title="Upload a Headshot Photo">
    <p>Upload a headshot photo of this person. Your photo will be uploaded once you select and crop your photo.</p>

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Choose a photo to upload</legend>

        Acceptable formats: .jpeg, .jpg, .gif, and .png and should be at least 72 DPI and 221x221.
        **<ajax:AsyncFileUpload ID="asyncImageUpload" 
              ThrobberID="throbber" 
              OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete" 
              OnUploadedComplete="AsyncFileUpload_Complete" 
              runat="server" />**
        <img src="/images/ajax-loader.gif" id="throbber" runat="server" style="display: none;" align="absmiddle" alt="loading" />
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Above is the div which contains the AsyncFileUpload control.  Like I said, if I move it outside the div it works fine.  I have already tried to change the enctype in the form and this is what it currently looks like:

```
<form id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" runat="server">
```

I have tried every suggestion I could find while trying to find a solution to this problem, but none seem to be working.  This isn't even in an update panel, so I'm not sure why it's not firing.

The only thing I can think of is that it has something to do with the div being hidden at first and then shown once the user clicks on the link.  I really hope someone can help cause I'm about to throw my computer out the window haha. Thanks in advance!

Code-behind:

```
protected void AsyncFileUpload_Complete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000);

    if (this.asyncImageUpload.HasFile)
    {
        string path = MapPath("~/images/uploads/") + Path.GetFileName(e.filename);
        this.asyncImageUpload.SaveAs(path);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you figure this problem out?  I'm having the same issue.